# how data moves in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Scenario: Source Blob storage stored in West Europe, destination, SQL Database in WEST Europe. Since data factory is not available in West Europe, if I create my data factory in North Europe and use the copy activity will my data be moved  via north Europe or will it stay in West Europe.

Comment: SQL Database in `WEST North`?? You mean north or west Europe or ..?

Comment: good catch corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Factory is merely an orchestrator: you define a workflow and a schedule and all the other things. It does not handle the data itself. It delegates the copy to the linked services involved. So in your case the data won't leave the West Europe region since both services live there.

Last time I created a job to copy data from blob in West Europe to a data lake also in West Europe the last step of the configuration showed a graphical summarize that even shown where the operations took place. All of them showed West Europe.

The closest thing to official documentation I could find was this graph:

[image]

taken from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-introduction). It shows that the data movement activity runs on the linked service. So the region in which that service lives determines where the action takes place.

Comment: this is what I was thinking since seems very illogical to move data between regions to move to the same region but then again stranger things have happened :). Many thanks for the detailed response.